# How stable is APC 3.1.x?

Tags: php, apache, apc

Is anyone using APC 3.1.x in production on a high volume site?  The 3.1 series is labeled a "beta" release, but it has some features that we'd really like to have (specifically, [performance improvements for apc_clear_cache('user')](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=13445) which didn't make 3.0.19)

So: are you successfully using APC 3.1.x on a very active site? (more than 1 PHP request per second [not including images/js/css])  Any signs of instability at all?

Comment: I updated my answer. So far so good running for several days with a busy forum. Currently request rate is 98.23 cache requests/second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it running on a production website. For several days - no crushes. I am using Apache worker + php-fpm.

File Cache Information

```
Cached Files    0 ( 0.0 Bytes)
Hits    4456420
Misses  11090047
Request Rate (hits, misses) 47.89 cache requests/second
Hit Rate    13.73 cache requests/second
Miss Rate   34.16 cache requests/second
Insert Rate 18.27 cache requests/second
Cache full count    4671279
```

User Cache Information

```
Cached Variables    64 ( 1.3 MBytes)
Hits    10480405
Misses  298883
Request Rate (hits, misses) 33.21 cache requests/second
Hit Rate    32.29 cache requests/second
Miss Rate   0.92 cache requests/second
Insert Rate 0.74 cache requests/second
Cache full count    34
```

Now I have been resetup cache size because of high query miss count.

Comment: Ok, I moved heavy forum to APC 3.1.x. It will have real load on workdays, but for now all going fine. Forum have about 80k hits per day.

Comment: I've got two boxes at over 1500+ req/sec.  Here's hoping it works just as well at that scale =D  Thanks for the info.

Comment: WOW... 1500+? What are you hosting? Wikipedia? :)

Answer (score 0):

Having been emboldened by FractalizeR's report of success, our ops guy rolled APC 3.1.3p1 to our 4 production PHP boxes (PHP 5.2.5, 5.2.10, 5.2.11) which are seeing 1000-2500 APC "system cache" hits per second currently.

So far so good.  I'll report back if anything comes up.
[image]

Comment: My god, guys, what are you hosting at 2500 cache hits per second? :)

Comment: 2,500 isn't a big deal. I'm currently at ~3466/s and approaching a billion opcache hits in the last 76hrs on one of out PHP servers. Before Xmas it was a lot busier.

Comment: Ah, the other PHP server was restarted at 6am, and in the 8.25hrs since then, it's had 6441 hits/sec. The quiet weekdays and overnights bring the averages down.

Comment: Maybe it is just an a/b test (example.com), I wonder how the rest of that production system might look when there even is a different PHP version on almost all servers according to the post... Also, spanning four servers for such a small bunch of missed cache hits looks odd...