# Is it advisable to use the latest PHP 5.3 compatible APC beta in a production environment?

Tags: php, apc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How stable is APC 3.1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970530/how-stable-is-apc-3-1-x)

It's been over a year since APC's last stable build. Has anyone got the latest APC beta running with PHP 5.3 on a high traffic production server?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970530/how-stable-is-apc-3-1-x

Answer (score 0):

### Beta versions are NEVER meant for production servers.

That being said, you should not use them on your high traffic production website.

**OP Clarification: Should he use MemCached then?**

Memcached is a distributed caching system, whereas APC is non-distributed - and mainly an opcode cache.

If (and only if) you have a web application which has to live on different webservers (loadbalancing), you have to use memcache for distributed caching. If not, just stick to APC and its cache.

You should always use an opcode cache, which APC is.

Comment: I guess I need to switch to memcached then, because I'm falling behind PHP releases.

Comment: I understand what memcached is and I do have a server cluster that I could implement it on. If I stick with APC I'm missing out on all the security and feature updates of PHP 5.3.